# Overhead of getting file metadata (last modified date)

Tags: java, filesystems

Am I correct in assuming that `java.io.File(file).lastModified()` will not cause the file itself to be loaded in any way and thus have minimal overhead? It's a really basic question, however I can't find any good information about it.

And setting the last modified date should have nearly no overhead either right?

If I understand it correctly this metadata is stored seperatedly from the file, so if I am not mistaken reading and writing this data shouldn't cost much, but just want to make sure as I would be using it as a central basis of a caching mechanism.

---

Based on the comments and replies so far, does that mean it would be more performant to do a directory listning with a filter for specifically my file only? As that *sounds* less performant IMHO.

Comment: Throws:
SecurityException - If a security manager exists and its SecurityManager.checkRead(java.lang.String) method denies **read access to the file**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.io.File(file)` returns a `File` object. So the file object is instantiated.

Each time there is you call `file.lastModified()` it ended up on native method call `java.io.UnixFileSystem.getLastModifiedTime(File)`.

Again, it happens each time you call.

So this is the overhead part of your concern.

Comment: Which suggests it's the same as `javaxt` on windows :D Good, may I also ask where or how you found that info? Just so I can find it myself next time hopefully :)

Comment: Take a look at the `File.lastModified()` code. You will notice something like `return fs.getLastModifiedTime(this);` And here for me, `java.io.UnixFileSystem.getLastModifiedTime(File)` is the implementation of `FileSystem` for Linux which is a native method. It should be something similar for other OS too.